# Express a phrase as compound

Tags: phrases, expressions, grammatical-number, names, compounds

I need to express this phrase as a short compound to be used as programming variable name (this phrase is in the context of a software user interface):

> the block showing current chatters

I have the following options:

1. Current Chatter Block
2. Current Chatters' Block

Which option would carry better sense? Option 1 is shorter but it doesn't seem to carry the correct meaning as the block contains a list of multiple chatter names, not just only 1 chatter name.

However, the second option when written as variable name, it would be: Current_Chatters_Block, this comes without the apostrophe, does it look ok?

Comment: Variable names are [specifically out of scope](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq) in ELU. I suggest you remove the final paragraph, and move the "Which option" question to the end.

Comment: i wanted to ask whether the second option written without the apostrophe looks ok in normal sense

Comment: @Paul: Define "normal sense." BTW, context is everything; I don't think a missing apostrophe is going to throw anyone – not in a variable name, especially in this SMS-driven society.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose whichever, there are no hard and fast rules in this situation.  I would choose the second option, "Current Chatters' Block"